# How to get a reference to RDD thats already persisted in memory?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I accidentally overridden my original reference to the RDD in memory, how would I get it back or set another reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `sc.getPersistentRDDs`, which returns all RDDs which have been marked as persistent (with `.cache()`).